# How can I find a colored marker inside of an image using HTML 5 Canvas and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas, fabricjs

I have a user-uploaded form that I am trying to crop based on the location of colored markers inside the image.

Using Fabric.js and Tracking.js, I can identify these markers under ideal conditions (i.e. when the user scans the image on a flatbed scanner).

Now, I want to make the system more robust by allowing a user to capture the image with the smartphone, meaning the image is on average much darker and the colored markers are harder to find.!

I can programmatically adjust the brightness of the image without any problems, but I am unable to reliably detect the locations of the markers.

I would like to develop an algorithm that will always find the area of the image with the highest concentration of blue, and record the coordinates around it.

Here is an example of the form:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Here's one method you could use:**

Use `context.getImageData` to get the pixel data of your image.

Convert each pixel to it's HSL equivalent.  HSL values allow you to more easily identify colors that are "bluish" rather than absolutely  blue.  As you mention, identifying colors that are not absolute is a requirement of a source image that might contain "noise" or that contains imperfect brightness and contrast levels.

The "H" in HSL is what we think of as color.  So you might declare that your original blue hue plus/minus 5% of original hue might be identified as "bluish".

Calculate the average X and average Y position of all "bluish" pixels.  This average will point towards your blue target.

You don't mention needing the average X/Y of the black targets.  If you have more than 1 target of the same color (like your black) then you must adjust your calculation by sorting black pixels by their general area on the image.

One way of dealing with multiple black targets is to:

- find a blackish pixel.  You can do this by iterating the pixel array until you find one.
- create a bounding box around that pixel that is twice the size of your target heart.
- calculate the average blackish X/Y inside that bounding box to identify that blackish target average.
- Now the tricky part...*reset all the pixels in that bounding box to transparent*.  Then refetch the pixel array of the modified image and do another search.  What this does is eliminate the "already found" first blackish target when searching for your next blackish target.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is similar to the approach I have been working on. I am still running into problems when trying to find the coordinates of the markers on a less ideal input image using tracking.js.